# Let V be a vector space over a field F and let V1, V2 be subspaces of V . Prove that the union of V1, V2 is a subspace of V if and only if

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space over a field F and let V1, V2 be subspaces
of V . Prove that the union of V1, V2 is a subspace of V if and only if

```
V1⊆V2 or V2⊆V1 .
```

Please someone explain why this holds?

Comment: Wrong site. You want https://math.stackexchange.com